# The Eigenvalue problem

Tags: vectors, mathematics, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

In [page 32](http://www.fisica.net/mecanica-quantica/Shankar%20-%20Principles%20of%20quantum%20mechanics.pdf) of R. Shankar's *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* is given the eigenvalue problem:

> We begin by rewriting Eq. (1.8.2)as $$(\Omega - \omega I)|V\rangle =|0\rangle  \tag{1.8.3}$$
>   Opening both sides with $(\Omega - \omega I)^{-1}$, assuming it exists, we get $$|V\rangle =(\Omega - \omega I)^{-1}|0\rangle \tag{1.8.4}$$
>   Now any finite operator(an operator with finite matrix elements) acting on the null vector can only give us a null vector. It therefore seems that in asking for a nonzero eigenvector $|V\rangle$, we are trying to get something for nothing out of Eq. (1.8.4). This is impossible. It follows that our assumption that the operator $(\Omega - \omega I)^{-1}$ exists(as a finite operator) is false. So we ask when this situation will obtain. Basic matrix theory tells us (see Appendix $\mathrm A. 1$) that the inverse of any matrix $M$ is given by $$M^{-1}= \frac{\mathrm{cofactor}  M}{\mathrm{det}(M)} \tag{1.8.5}$$
>   Now the cofactor of $M$ is finite if $M$ is. Thus what we need is the vanishing of the determinant. The condition for nonzero eigenvectors is therefore $$\mathrm{det}(\Omega - \omega I) =0 \tag{1.8.6}$$

Why is a vanishing determinant necessary to find nonzero eigenvectors?

Comment: Isn't this just stating that if the determinant of a matrix is zero, it doesn't have an inverse?

Comment: You can define the determinant of a linear operator in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space *only* in some suitable situation (*e.g.* trace class operators that are bigger than one). You should use proper operator theory to study eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: @Tyberius, you are right. I reason that $\Omega - \omega I$, which is finite, cannot have an inverse, for we do not want a zero eigenvector. For this to happen, the det should be zero. We then find the eigenvalues of the operator whose eigenvector is $|V\rangle$

Comment: You can also think of the determinant as being the product of the eigenvalues of an operator. Equation 1.8.3 tells you that the operator $\Omega- \omega I$ has an eigenvalue of zero, thus the determinant must be zero.

Answer (score 3):

The operator $(\Omega - \omega I)$ can be seen as a matrix. But to be inversible, a matrix needs its determinant to be non-zero. Why does it need to be non-zero ?

Let's take a matrix A, which we'll assume is inversible and let's demonstrate that its determinant can't be zero :
$$
det(A) \cdot det (A^{-1}) = det(A \cdot A^{-1}) = det (I) = 1
$$
(with the property of multiplication of determinants)
thus $det(A)$ can't be zero.

Answer (score 1):

For, for notational clarity, you want to understand $\vert 0\rangle$ as the $0$ vector.

Start with 
$$
(\Omega-\omega I)\vert V\rangle=\vert 0\rangle \, . \tag{1}
$$
If $(\Omega-\omega I)$ as a matrix has an inverse - call it $(\Omega-\omega I)^{-1}$ as you do, then multiply both sides of (1) by this inverse to get
$$
(\Omega-\omega I)^{-1}(\Omega-\omega I)\vert V\rangle 
= \vert V\rangle =\vert 0\rangle \tag{2}
$$
so that your eigenvector $\vert V\rangle $ is the $\vert 0\rangle$ vector.  If you do not want $\vert V\rangle$ to be $\vert 0\rangle$, the assumption that $(\Omega-\omega I)$ has an inverse must be false.  For this to be false, it must be that 
$$
\hbox{Det}\left(\Omega-\omega I\right)=0\, .
$$
Alternatively, if the determinant is NOT $0$, then the inverse will exists and you find from (2) that $\vert V\rangle$ is the $0$ vector.